# Mysql query to match 2 criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as below and want to find all IPs that have had at least 1 instance of 200 and 404 response. Am trying to achieve this by join or a recursive query but unable to get the correct output. Expected output : 1.5.10.15. Please advise.

```
+-----------------+------------+----------+
| ip              | statuscode |id(primary)|
+-----------------+------------+----------+
| 1.2.3.4         |        200 |        1 |
| 1.3.5.9         |        404 |        2 |
| 2.4.6.8         |        404 |        3 |
| 1.2.3.4         |        200 |        4 |
| 2.4.6.8         |        301 |        5 |
| 1.3.5.9         |        301 |        6 |
| 1.5.10.15       |        404 |        7 |
| 1.5.10.15       |        200 |        8 |
```

Comment: add tab structure and tried query also.

Comment: Why would  you specify the mechanism to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select ip
from t
where statuscode in (200, 404)
group by ip
having min(statuscode) <> max(statuscode);
```

I cannot think of a better method using joins and recursive subqueries seem not useful at all for this.

If you have a separate table of `ip`s (which seems likely), then `exists` is likely to be the most efficient method:

```
select i.*
from ips i
where exists (select 1
              from statuses s
              where s.ip = i.ip and s.statuscode = 404
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from statuses s
              where s.ip = i.ip and s.statuscode = 200
             );
```

For this, you want an index on `statuses(ip, statuscode)`.

Comment: Interesting how efficient it will be with to `exists`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery for the  ip having count = 2

```
select * from my_table m.ip 
inner join ( 
  select ip
  from  my_table  
  where statuscode  in  (200,400)
  group by ip 
  having count ( distinct statuscode) = 2 

  ) t on t.ip =
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from ip_table A
where exists (select 1 from ip_table where A.ip = ip and status_code = 404)
  and (select 1 from ip_table where A.ip = ip and status_code = 200)
```

If you really need at least one 1 instance of 200 **AND** 404.